# Canceling a datagrid cellendediting does not stop editing?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm implementing a wpf datagrid cellendediting event, which performs an action that can fail. If the action fails I set the event as cancelled. This is a basic example:

```
private void datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEvent e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Which does cancel the value from being set, however the datagridcell is still in the edit state. I cannot figure out how to actually cause the cell to end editing when I cancel. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call CancelEdit :

```
private void datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEvent e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    (sender as DataGrid).CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Cell);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but calling CancelEdit causes recursion as datagrid_CellEndEditing gets called again. I did add a if(e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Cancel) return; but that seemed hackey. Is this the prober way?

Comment: I'm wondering if `e.Cancel = true` is necessary if we call `CancelEdit`.  You could try it without this line.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution was so close - you need to call CancelEdit without setting e.Cancel to prevent that the value is set to the new value:

```
private void datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEvent e)
{
    (sender as DataGrid).CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Cell);
}
```

Another possibility is to keep editing the TextBox and set the focus again to the textbox in case the user clicked outside:

```
private void datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEvent e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    (sender as DataGrid).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        (sender as DataGrid).SelectedIndex = e.Row.GetIndex();
        e.EditingElement.Focus();
    }));
}
```